# SQL Server : sum of several selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I have the following code which presents the results in a table with several columns.

```
SELECT 
   ref, design, 
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 34 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPP', 
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 28 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPM', 
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 42 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RNPM', 
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RAM', 
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt2) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RA' ,
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 59 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'GD'
FROM   
    bi(nolock) temp
WHERE  
    (temp.ndos = 34 OR temp.ndos = 28  OR temp.ndos = 42  OR temp.ndos = 68) 
    AND temp.bofref LIKE #1# 
    AND temp.ref NOT LIKE ' ' 
GROUP BY 
    ref, design 
ORDER BY 
    ref
```

I now want to sum the values of some of the select in a new column, for example I wanted to sum the columns "LPP, RNPM and RA" in a total column, however I am not able to get it to work.

How can it be done?

Comment: Remove subqueries and use case instead. Having like in where clause is like killing your query for no reasons.

Comment: I dont know other way to do that. #1# is a variable that is written by user and can be in several formats like xx.xxxx.xx or xx.xxxx or xx. and the code has to look for all results that match the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly you could sum the single columns

```
  SELECT 
          ref
        , design
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 34 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPP', 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 28 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPM', 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 42 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RNPM', 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RAM', 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt2) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RA' ,
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 59 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'GD',  
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 34 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) + 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 28 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) + 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 42 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) + 
     Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) as TOTAL_COLUMN 

  FROM   bi(nolock) temp
  WHERE  ( temp.ndos = 34
        OR temp.ndos = 28 
        OR temp.ndos = 42 
        OR temp.ndos = 68 ) 
     AND temp.bofref like #1# 
     AND temp.ref NOT LIKE ' ' 
  GROUP  BY ref, 
        design 
  ORDER  BY ref
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to wrap your query in another:

```
SELECT sub.*,
       LPP + RNPM + RA as LPP_RNPM_RA
FROM (       
    SELECT ref, design, 
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 34 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPP', 
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 28 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'LPM', 
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 42 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RNPM', 
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RAM', 
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt2) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 68 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'RA' ,
       Isnull((SELECT Sum(qtt) FROM bi(nolock) WHERE  bi.ndos = 59 AND bofref like #1# AND bi.ref = temp.ref GROUP  BY ref), 0) AS 'GD'
    FROM   bi(nolock) temp
    WHERE  temp.ndos IN (34, 28, 42, 68) 
       AND temp.bofref like #1# 
       AND temp.ref NOT LIKE ' ' 
    GROUP  BY ref, 
          design 
    ) as sub
ORDER  BY ref
```

Note you can use the `IN` operator instead of the `OR` combinations you have in your `where` clause.

Also, the way you sum looks awkward: don't do subqueries, but do this in your `select`:

```
       Sum(CASE WHEN temp.ndos = 34 THEN qtt ELSE 0 END) AS 'LPP',
```

... etc.

Comment: I try this but with no results.
There is no error but there is no results too.
I will try to see if i can find what is wrong.
Thanks